# Consumer is not authorized to access %resources for rest API Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I created a new customer and got the token perfectly but when I try to access any API like

```
http://myhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me?Authorization=Bearerhy23vc01x9s1jd2t8gho47g58trllc0b
```

got the error

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
<message>Consumer is not authorized to access %resources</message>
<parameters>
<resources>self</resources>
</parameters>
  <trace>#0 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator.php(70): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator-&gt;checkPermissions()
#1 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(80): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator-&gt;validate()
#2 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(299): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver-&gt;resolve()
#3 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest-&gt;processApiRequest()
#4 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest-&gt;dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor-&gt;dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http-&gt;launch()
#7 /var/www/myhost.com/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap-&gt;run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#8 {main}</trace>
</response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a space between Bearer and token as :

```
Bearer hy23vc01x9s1jd2t8gho47g58trllc0b
```

not:

```
Bearerhy23vc01x9s1jd2t8gho47g58trllc0b
```